# Javascript - How to use javascript callbacks for blocking

Tags: javascript, node.js

This is a simplified version of a problem I'm stuck on. I want to be able to create a scheduler class so that it has a function, addTask(), that takes in a task function as a parameter. The class also has a begin function, runSchedule(), that runs any number of added tasks synchronously, or in order. I think that maybe I can do something like this with a sequence of Promises, but I haven't used Promises before but researching and trying to use it didn't yield me anything that worked.

Is there a way to store the function parameter to addTask(), then during a call to runSchedule() call all the added the tasks in order? If the tasks run successfully call the success callback. If one task fails, then stop and don't execute any more tasks, and call the error callback.

```
class Schedule {
    constructor( ) {
        this.tasks = []
    }

    addTask( task ) {
        this.tasks.push( task )
        // added to list of promises here
        // currently just adding function to an array
    }

    runSchedule( success, error ) {
        try {
            // run the tasks here
            success()
        } catch (e) {
            error()
        }
    }
}

s = new Schedule()

// first
s.addTask( function(goToNext, stopRunning) {
    this.value1 = true
    goToNext();
});

// second
s.addTask( function(goToNext, stopRunning) {
    if (!this.value1) {
        stopRunning();
    }
    var self = this
    setTimeout(function() {
        self.value2 = true
        goToNext();
    }, 1000);
});

// run first task, then second task
s.runSchedule(function () {
    console.log(this.value1)
    console.log(this.value2)
}, function (error) {
    console.log("error: " + error)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Schedule {
    constructor( ) {
        this.tasks = []
    }

    addTask( task ) {
        this.tasks.push( task )
        // added to list of promises here
        // currently just adding function to an array
    }

    runSchedule( success, error ) {
        try {
            run(this.tasks.pop());// use tasks.shift() if you want to go from begining 

        } catch (e) {
            error()
        }
    }

    run(task){
        task()
        .then(()=>{
            if(this.tasks>0){
                run(this.tasks.pop())
            }
            else{
                success()
            }
        })
        .catch(()=>{
            //call your failure here 
        })
    }
}
```

And tasks should be added like this

```
s.addTask(function(){
    return new Promise((success, failure)=>{
        //do your work at the end call success() or failure()
    });
});
```

Added a new method run which takes a `task` as argument and executes if execution is successful then it recursively calls run until all task is finished if all are finished than call success(), if error is there then handle your failures

We have to change the tasks , each task returns promise , inside the promise do your work if success call `success()` else `failure()`

NB: not able to test this, writing form phone, please look for typo

Answer (score 0):

STRONG SUGGESTION: to the extent it might make you think of "threads" (in other languages", please consider purging the word "task" from your vocabulary.  With Javascript, you're much better off thinking in terms of [asynchronous programming](https://blog.sessionstack.com/how-javascript-works-event-loop-and-the-rise-of-async-programming-5-ways-to-better-coding-with-2f077c4438b5) - where any particular work item could finish in potentially any order.

Definitely read up on [Promises](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/promises).

In short:

1. You can return a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) for some work item that will complete "asynchronously".
2. You can "chain" promises together with a [Promise.then()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) callback to ensure one work item doesn't start before the previous completes.
3. You can also save promises together in an array, and continue when they *all* complete (regardless of which items complete "first"): [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).

One more link you might find helpful:

> https://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript-promises-for-dummies
>
> Javascript Promises are not difficult. However, lots of people find it
>   a little bit hard to understand at the beginning. Therefore, I would
>   like to write down the way I understand promises, in a dummy way.
>
> ```
> 1. Understanding Promises
> 2. Creating a Promise
> 3. Consuming Promises
> 4. Chaining Promises
> 5. Promises are Asynchronous
> 6. Promises in ES5, ES6/2015, ES7/Next
> 7. Why Promises and When to Use Them?
> 8. New Kid On the Block: Observables
> 9. Summary
> ```